# At what level is WCAG enforceable?

Tags: americans-with-disabilities-act

[Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) is the standard under the American Disabilities Act.
The level AAA clause 1.2.6 states every speech or video must have sign language alternatives. It is not possible for live or video classes or even for prerecorded youtube videos is there a way around it?Is the WCAG level AAA binding by law and requires all video uploaders to provide caption and signs?

Comment: WCAG are *standards*, not laws. The American Disabilities Act is the law. Are you asking for a way to undermine the law in your specific case?

Comment: Why will someone want to undermine law , what was meant is that is WCAG AAA enforceable meaning is it compulsory for allb youtuber's to provide sign language translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCAG is a *standard*, not a *law*.  It is one way of providing the accommodations required under the Americans with Disabilities Act, but not the only way.

Additionally, the ADA only requires *reasonable* accommodations, not "any accommodation that anyone can think of".  In my experience, compliance with WCAG at the "AA" level is usually considered sufficient to be "reasonable".

Comment: Is compliance only till WCAG A meet ADA?